# Advance audio editing for blender

Tags: audio

Is there any plug-in for editing audio in blender? 
advance editing audio similar lmms or fruity loops

Comment: [Ardour](https://ardour.org/) is open source and advanced.

Answer (score 4):

Blender has a [Video Sequence Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/introduction.html) which allows very simple editing of an audio clip such as cutting and volume adjustment. Audio clips can then be placed in sync with a video clip to then be encoded together into a final file.

All other audio editing or generating needs to be done in other applications such as LMMS, Garage Band, FL Studio or Audacity before being added to blender.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linux, then Jack Audio can help.  You can have Blender and Ardour open at the same time and they both can share the same transport. This means that when you hit the play button BOTH programs run and share the same clock. If you touch the timeline on either program, both go to the same time stamp. Make your Video changes in Blender and the audio changes in Ardour arbitrarily, as needed. When you have completed your Audio editing, export the mix from Ardour into a wave file, then drop it into Blender. It will be synced because your editing was done using the same clock / transport. Then bake the soundtrack in the final render.

Make sure you choose to use Jack audio in both programs. Even more impressive is MuseScore will also join the party and you can run all three at the same time, synced together. This means that you can compose music while watching the video and record live too.  Sick :-)

Comment: Wow, that's awesome!  I didn't realise JACK could sync play heads across programs.  Thanks!